# computation of high order bessel function at large variable value

Tags: mathematical-software

My work involves computation of high order bessel function at large variable value. Within MATLAB, this has been done without any problems. However, in order to scale up the problem, I have tuned to writing C++ code with MPI. Of course, the step to generate bessel function is done by invoking some libraries. To put the problem concrete, let me consider this very specific bug.

In matlab, suppose I wish to compute $J_{46341}(86840.0)$, and

> matlab gives me: besselj(46341,86840)=0.001309896212292

However, a simple test example to call

> gsl_sf_bessel_Jn_e returns "ERROR: NaN"

and I have checked at order 46340, both matlab and gsl returns the same answer 0.00292895 within acceptable accuracies. One more step in GSL results in the NaN error while matlab still retains a good accurate numerical answer.

I did try to use recurrence relations to generate higher order values, from a-not-so-small-order, say from order of 20000 and up, however, this only delays the NaN error without completely solving the problem.

Switching my attention to other available software libraries out there, I tried NAG, but to my utter disappointment,

> nag_bessel_j_alpha (s18ekc) has constraint of abs(nl)<=101

, in other words, it can only compute up to order of 101 and it is clearly not in my interest of study.

So, my question is fairly simple:

> Is there a more reliable library approach to obtain high order bessel
>   function value for large x?

Asymptotically, bessel function approaches 0, I can surely set those values to zero if the tail is approaching the underflow limit. However, the NaN problem seems to occur somewhat between strongly oscillating curve and asymptotically decaying tail.

Comment: I agree this is off topic and given the answer below the OP does not appear to have done sufficient research. It seems like a bug in GSL which a few minutes investigation would have revealed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the recurrence relation $$J_{n+1}(z) = \frac{2 (n-1)}{z} J_{n-1}(z) - J_{n-2}(z)$$
to get to a high order from a pair of values of small order.

For example, the Python code

```
from scipy.special import j0, j1

def jn(n,z):
    a, b = j0(z), j1(z)
    for k in range(2,n+1):
        b, a = b*2*(k-1)/z - a, b
    return b

jn(46341, 86840.0)
```

outputs

```
0.0013098962123461375
```

which is essentially as accurate as the initial values.

If you run into NaNs, it's possible that you need to use higher-precision arithmetic.

Another possibility is to use uniform asymptotic expansions (see http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.20).

Comment: If you run into NaNs that's usually a sign your problem is ill-conditioned; reaching for higher precision is probably not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these [2009 slides by John Harrison (of Intel).](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/slides/arith-09jun09/slides.pdf)